# Get all comments with nearest to furthest and vice versa location wise in ElasticSearch

Tags: database, laravel, elasticsearch, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have an application in Laravel, data is stored in ElasticSearch.
I want to add two options in app

**1-Show Nearest**
It will be used to get all comments from the nearest location(of the user) to the furthest location and sorted by location.
**example**
One user commented from Pakistan and 2 other people commented from India and the USA.
So, when I'll click Show Nearest then Pakistan users comment will be top then India comment on 2nd number and USA comment on 3rd number (In case my location is Pakistan).

**2-Show Furthest**
It will be used to get all comments from the furthest location(of the user) to the nearest location and sorted by location
**example**
Suppose example given above, So, when I'll click Show Furthest then USA comment will be top then India comment on 2nd number and Pakistan comment on 3rd number (In case my location is Pakistan).

This search will be base on Latitude Longitude stored on ElasticSearch for each comment.

Fileds are as follows:

> post_id(type:text), text(type:text) location(array of lat long) e.g location:[ -71.34, 41.12 ]

My query is as follows:-

> ```
> [
>  "query"=>[
>
>     "bool"=>[
>         "filter"=>[
>             "match"=>[
>                 "post_id" => $id
>             ]
>         ]
>     ]
> ],
>
> "sort" => [
>     [
>         "_geo_distance" => [
>             "location" => [
>                 "lat" => $lat,
>                 "lon" => $long
>             ],
>             "order" => "asc",
>             "unit" => "km"
>         ]
>     ]
> ],
> ```
>
> ]
>
> This is not working
>   Kindly help me I'm new in elasticsearch. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by geo_distance sorting.
Make sure that your field is of geo_point on the basis of the comments of which you want to sort by geo distance.

The pin is you location based on which other location distance will be calculated

Here is an example

```
GET /_search
{
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "pin.location" : {
                    "lat" : 40,
                    "lon" : -70
                },
                "order" : "asc",
                "unit" : "km"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

For more detail on this and if you want to play with more setting, Here is a link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#geo-sorting

Comment: in case i want check comments for specific post then should I add must check above sort? and in case lat long are store in this format how to use in query
        "coordinates" : [ 
            40.7387032765573, 
            -73.9887174954924
        ]

Comment: and also tell me about 40 and -70 .. will it be users lat long who is going to click option?

Comment: right it will be lat lon of user, around whom he wants to see comments

Comment: for query you can just add a match query to it : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: but the above query is not according to my need...because you're sorting base on lat long it is not according to my need e.g I want that Pakistan comment at 1st and India at 2nd and the USA on 3rd...

Comment: So a user sitting and commenting in Pakistan will see comments of it first then india then usa. Whenever you sort based on a document, you will always have to provide a pin location right, from where you want to measure the distance of the comments, this is that

Comment: Plus query is for filtering the documents, like post, or anything else

Comment: thank you,I'll try this and let you know if I face any problem

Comment: Lat Long are store as 
"lat" => "20.5937"
 "long" => "78.9629" in this case what will be above query? also consider user who is going to click "show nearest"  has "lat"=>"30.3753"  , "long"=>"69.3451". Thank you

Comment: For queries related to distance to work, you would need your latLon field as geo_point type. Have  a look over here . https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

Comment: if I'm storing lat long as "location": [ -71.34, 41.12 ] then should I remove pin from pin.location?

Comment: Kindly see my query in Qestion and make it correct .. Thank you